# C# Windows worms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Описать класс, представляющий треугольник. Предусмотреть методы для создания объектов, расчета площади, периметра и точки пересечения медиан. Описать свойство для получения состояния объекта. При невозможности построения треугольника обрабатывать исключения ВСЕ Я ЭТО СДЕЛАЛ ТОКА НУЖНО ЧТО БЫ ЭТО БЫЛО В ВИНДОВС ФОРМС И ЧТО БЫ Я ЭТО ВСЕ ВВОДИЛ ВРУЧНУЮ ТИПА НА КНОПКИ А НЕ В КОНСОЛИ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace test
{
    abstract class Figure
    {
        //Площадь фигуры
        public abstract double square();
        public abstract double perimeter();
        //Пересечение медиан
        public abstract double median();
    }
    class Triangle : Figure
    {
        double a, b, c; //Стороны
                        //Конструктор
        public Triangle(double a, double b, double c)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }
        public override double square()
        {
            //Используем формулу Герона
            double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
            return Math.Sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
        }
        public override double perimeter()
        {
            return a + b + c;
        }

                public override double median()
                {
            return (a + b + c) / 3;
                }
            }


        class Test
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Figure f1;
                f1 = new Triangle(3, 4, 5);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Периметр трикутника = " + f1.perimeter());
                System.Console.WriteLine("Площина трикутника = " + f1.square());
                  System.Console.WriteLine("Перетин медіан = " + f1.median());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос в чем заключается ?

Comment: НУЖНО КОД написать тока он у меня эсть но я не знаю как связать его в виндовс формс

Comment: Покажите тогда код

Comment: дайте свой телеграм что бы я его вам скинул а то тут немогу

Comment: а то не знаю как тут скинуть

Comment: все я тут закинул но суть такова что бы я вводил данные типа для сторон труегольника например 2 4 10 и оно мне считало то что выше пишите но это не нужно на консоль а на виндовс формс типа з кнопками и полем для ввода что то такое

Comment: @SPUPER Можете пожалуйста не капсить? Это дурной тон и неуважительно к другим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение [image: Форма]

1. создаете форму
2. добавляетe из ToolBox -> Textbox x3
3. Добавляете кнопку ToolBox ->Button
4. Добавляете список Toolbox -> listbox
5. Создаете Класс Figure и Triangle
6. Нажимаете 2 раза на кнопку в дизайне форм 
   получаете метод :

---

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

внутри этого метода добавить

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       double a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
       double b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
       double c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);


        Figure f1;
        f1 = new Triangle(a,b,c);

        listBox1.Items.Add("Периметр трикутника = " + f1.Perimeter());
        listBox1.Items.Add("Площина трикутника = " + f1.Square());
        listBox1.Items.Add("Перетин медіан = " + f1.median());
    }
```

резльтат [image: Результат]

Comment: Описать свойство для получения состояния объекта. При невозможности построения треугольника обрабатывать исключения ---А ВОТ ТУТ ЧТО СДЕЛАТЬ А ТО ДАЖЕ НЕ ПОНИМАЮ ЗАДАНИЯ ЧТО ТУТ ПИШЕТ

Comment: все то что в нутри метода `button1_Click` должно находится в блоке `try catch`   это нужно для того чтобы если вы введете в место цифр буквы или что то другое программа смогла обработать эту ошибку

Comment: ошибку показивает мой код я вставил в клас а твой на кнопку но ошибку выдает

Comment: f1.Perimeter() и f1.Square()); с большой буквы  `P` и `S` а у вас с маленькой

Comment: все уже работает тока эсть еще одна проблема в моем коде в классе тоесть нужно добавить статический элемент как это сделать и куда его добавить

Comment: ниже этого `double a, b, c;` напишите static double s это будет статистическая переменная

Comment: у вас эсть какойто месенджер что бы я вам написал и подробно расказала